# valueChangeListner not firing for <rich:select> tag

Tags: richfaces

using "value" attribute of rich:select tag value is not getting stored in the bean property,ie
whenever I'm making a new selection from the list,the new value is not getting stored within the bean property,it retaining the initial value of the instance field.

This is my code:

I had a property baseSkin,in the bean skinBean.I have defined its setter and getters also.
Still not getting the value whenever I'm making a new selection

Answer (score 1):

The `valueChangeListener` doesn't work the way people would expect it to. It gets executed when the form is submitted and the resolver makes a check against the current value.

You haven't included the code but I assume you want the new value to be stored in the bean immediately after you click the item in the list, that can be done:

```
<rich:select id="select">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.list}" var="item" itemLabel="#{item.value}" />
    <a4j:ajax event="selectitem" oncomplete="updateBean(#{rich:component('select')}.getValue())" />
</rich:select>

<a4j:jsFunction name="updateBean">
    <a4j:param assignTo="#{bean.value}" name="value" />
</a4j:jsFunction>
```

Of course, you have to check if the value really did change because the ajax listener will trigger even if you select the same value again.